# {{ directory }} not available in parts of menu--main.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

Printing {{ directory }} at the start of the file works fine. But a bit further it's no longer availble:

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
    **{{ directory }} {# THIS WORKS #}**
    {% import _self as menus %}
    {% if items %}
        {% if menu_level == 0 %}
            <ul{{ attributes }}>
        {% else %}
            <ul id="navigation">
        {% endif %}
        {% for item in items %}
        <li class="active">
            <a href="{{ item.url }}">
                **{{ directory }} {# THIS DOESN'T WORK #}**
                <img src="{{ directory }}/images/menuicon.png" alt="" />
                {{ item.title }}
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Be careful about using `{{ directory }}` twig variable in a theme that you intend to use as a base theme and create sub-themes for:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277278

Answer (score 1):

The second occurrence of `{{ directory }}` is within a Twig macro. As the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) mentions, you cannot access the outer variables in a macro:

> But as with PHP functions, macros don't have access to the current template variables.

You can however pass `_context` through a macro parameter and access `directory` that way, or pass it explicitly.